# Getting weird error 'db.Close undefined (type *gorm.DB has no field or method Close)

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am writing code for a pet-project working with golang 1.19.5, immundb and gorm.io (version 1.22.4) but once I create the db connection object using gorm.Open(xxx). I am able to use the AutoMigrate function from the gorm.DB structure but when I atteped to use the Close() function I get the error: db.Close undefined (type *gorm.DB has not field or method Close)

When I run the go doc gorm.DB (partial below), I see that there is a Close function as well as the AutoMigrate function which I am using without issue.

```
func (s *DB) AutoMigrate(values ...interface{}) *DB
func (s *DB) Begin() *DB
func (s *DB) BeginTx(ctx context.Context, opts *sql.TxOptions) *DB
func (s *DB) BlockGlobalUpdate(enable bool) *DB
func (s *DB) Callback() *Callback
func (s *DB) Close() error
```

I don't understand why I can't use the Close fuction.

I am using vscode, I use the terminal function within vscode and I attempted to open the vscode from the project directory to make sure it is reading the go.mod file properly. I linked the gorm.io directory to the project directory through a symbolic link just incase there is an issue reading the package. Nothing has actual made a difference.

Comment: See the [documentation for gorm.DB version 1.22.4](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm@v1.22.4#DB).  The type does not have a Close method.

Comment: You are correct. I have a mismatch with the gorm packages I am using, given that when I ran 'go doc gorm.DB' the output showed a Close function, but when I compile it, go uses version 1.22.4, which does not have it. Thank you.